# C# get all elements of array

Tags: c#, arrays

Using `array.ElementAt(0);` we can get the element at index 0 of the array. Is there a method to get all the elements in an array?

```
string[] arr1 = {'abc', 'def', 'ghi'}
Library.Results["TEST_ACTUALVALUE"] = "The results are: " + arr1;
```

TEST_ACTUALVALUE is a column in my report.xls file. The above writes System.string[] in my excel file.

Comment: Are you wanting to do something special with all the elements? Like concatenate them all together into a big string?

Comment: How do you want to store `all the elements`? In another array? In a list? Something else entirely?

Comment: I may be a layman here, but isn't the array "all elements" in it of itself?

Comment: I want to output the elements in an excel file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You already have all of the elements in the array...the array itself.

The simple answer is iterate over them:

```
foreach(var item in array)
{
    // work with item here
}
```

Or if you'd rather deal with indexes:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    var item = array[i];
    // work with item here
}
```

Comment: Do you maybe know what would this error appear for array[i]: `Cannot apply indexing to an expression of type System.Array`?

Comment: @maf-soft - Nowhere in the OP's post does it ask how to modify the elements of the array. It simply set's the value in a separate dictionary.

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to know what you mean by "get all the elements in an array" because you already have all the elements....in the array.

If you mean concatinating a string from a string array then something like:

```
var concatinatedString = String.Concat(myArrayOfStrings);
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a hundred ways to skin that cat.  Largely it should depend on what you wish to do with all the elements. Heres the old school for loop method:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    something = array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you'd do this, but there is a `array.All` available.  Try that?

Comment: not my code, but using this... int[] array = { 10, 20, 30 }; bool a = array.All(element => element >= 10); // Are all elements >= 10? YES

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to get the elements for there are many methods you can look into

Get all the elements in an array

```
for(int x = 0; x < array.Length; x++)
{
    something = array[x];
    somethingElse = array.ElementAt(x);
}
```

Make an array a list to get all values:

```
List<T> myList = array.ToList<T>();
```

From here you can do all list methods with that array to get all values.

If you are trying to take the sum of every element use:

```
sum = array.Sum();
```

To get the max/min value in the array:

```
max = array.Max();
min = array.Min();
```

To get the average:

```
double average = array.Average(num => Convert.ToInt64(num));
```

There are many other ways to get all information from an array, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The question is how to join a string array together. Solution:

```
... = "The results are: " + String.Join (", ", arr1);
```

And a note: you don't have to and should not use `array.ElementAt(0)` to get an element. Use `array[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Going to go out on a limb here and recommend using a loop?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `ElementAt`? You can just use the indexer:

```
var value = array[0];
```

In general:

```
var ithValue = array[i];
```

Answer (score 2):

The Array class implements the IList, ICollection, and IEnumerable interfaces. So you can use any needed method of these interfaces.

Eventually, you can write foreach loop to traverse through array.

Answer (score 0):

```
//IF the array type is string, you can follow below:
//else you need to convert to string 1st.

String Result = "";

For (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
 Result = Result + array[i];
}

// The result will consist all the array element.
```